# How to require a login every time the app appears

Tags: ios, privacy, touch-id

In order to (at least partially) secure the data displayed in my app, I want to require users to login every time they view the app. I have a similar app called Keeper that requires login when the app first opens and when the user brings the app back from running in the background, though the difference being that when it returns from the background, it restarts at the previous view once the user logs in. How would I handle this requirement? I'd like to just use touchID, though in reality I imagine I'll use a 4-number passcode as a backup. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the life cycle delegate methods of UIApplicationDelegate.

Comment: Make login view controller  as window.rootviewcontroller in  enterForground method in AppDelegate class

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    showLoginView()

    return true
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

    // This gets called when the app comes back from Background
    showLoginView()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    // NOTE: You don't want to call showLoginView() here
    // Because this gets called even when the app becomes active after user drags down Notification Center, or drags up Utility Panel.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring up your login dialog in the "applicationDidBecomeActive:" method in your appDelegate.